# How to handle Stomp JS disconnect in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket

In the project I've been working on, I found a problem with Stomp JS client disconnect.
It's about a case when user closes the tab in browser or when there's a problem with internet connection. In other words, I want to be able to handle this disconnect java side (server side). **Is it possible?**

I already have code that handles Websocket opening and it works fine, what I want to achieve is to handle connection closing (both expected and unexpected cases)

Here's a piece of my HTML file that includes Stomp JS related code (I can provide Java code as well if it's necessary):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        connect(); 
    });

    var stompClient = null;

    function connect() {
        var socket = new SockJS('/lock-document');
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            stompClient.subscribe('/notify-open-documents/${id}', function (messageOutput) {
                console.log('Receiving message: ' + JSON.parse(messageOutput.body));
            });
            sendName();
        });
    }

    function disconnect() {
        if (stompClient !== null) {
            stompClient.disconnect();
        }
        console.log("Disconnected");
    }

    function sendName() {
        console.log("Sending message : " + JSON.stringify({'documentId' : "${id}" }));
        stompClient.send('/ws/lock-document', {}, JSON.stringify({'documentId': "${id}"}));
    }

</script>
```

Comment: I think I probably found the answer here: http://www.sergialmar.com/2014/03/detect-websocket-connects-and-disconnects-in-spring-4/

Comment: Take a look at a possible implementation here: https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sergialmar/wschat/event/PresenceEventListener.java